# how to use DllImport in metro-style app

Tags: dllimport

I'm trying to use `DLLImport` in **metro-style** project.

```
[DllImport("pjsipDlld.dll")]
private static extern int dll_init();

void test()
{
 dll_init();
}
```

I copied **pjsipDlld.dll** and its dependencies to the output directory. The project build seems fine. It crashes when I launch it though.

and when debugging i get this exception "DllNotFoundException" when calling the native method.

I followed the very same procedure in a WPF project and every thing went well with no errors or crashes. Am I missing something in **metro-style** app?

Comment: Did you try to copy pjsipDlld.dll and its dependencies to some directory available through PATH, like Windows directory? AFAIK, metro application does not run directly from the project output directory. It is first installed by Visual Studio, and then executed.

Comment: i did, still the same error.